# Issue in generating report in Excel from TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

I am facing a issue while generating report from `Excel->Team->New Report->Select Query`.

I am not able to get data for fields (Acceptance Criteria & Description) fields.

How can I download data for these type of fields. Basically I wanted to report blank 'Acceptance Criteria' Features using this option as it is not possible get this data in TFS 2013 through Query in TFS 2013.

But when I try to export data into excel (Open in Excel) from Query I am able to get Acceptance Criteria & Description fields. Why not able to get the same while creating New report & how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is "not able"? do you get an error?

Comment: Warning messages it is giving saying can't display 'Acceptance criteria' & 'Description' type of fields.

Comment: Hi Kumar,just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Do you have any other concern? **Description** and **Acceptance Criteria** both are **HTML data-type** fields which could not use to generate a report in excel. Sorry for any inconvenience, it's by designed.

Answer (score 1):

Not every kind of fields can be used when you generated a report even they could be exported in Excel. There are some limitations.

> **Q: Which fields can't I use to generate a report?**
>
> A: Even though you can include non-reportable fields in your query
>   field criteria or as a column option, they won't be used to generate a
>   report.
>
> - **Description**, History, and **other HTML data-type fields**. These fields    won't be added to the PivotTable or used to generate a
>     report. Excel    does not support generating reports on these fields.
> - Fields with filter criteria that specify the Contains, Contains    Words, Does Not Contain, or Does Not Contain Words operators will not 
>     be added to the PivotTable. Excel does not support these operators.

`Acceptance Criteria`

*Reference name=Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria, **Data type=HTML***

That's why you are not able to do this, and warning messages it is giving saying can't display `Acceptance criteria` & `Description` type of fields

More details please take a look at our official link-- [Create Excel reports from a work item query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports?view=azure-devops-2019#q-which-fields-cant-i-use-to-generate-a-report)